# redirect a part of page of old site to new site web.config

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, google-index

i have renewed the structure of a website with the same dns, and now i want to redirect all the indexed pages to specific url, a lot of this are very old page and i redirect it to the homepage, other page are similar to my new site so i want to redirect it to a specific page.

for example the page www.mysite.com/page.asp?id=1&article=22 to www.mysite.com/page/22

i have tried to use this in the web.config

```
<rule name="Reindirizzamento_sito_vecchio_1" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="http://isaporideicastelliromani.it/novita_gastronomiche.asp?page=2&amp;idpage=7&amp;active=7" />
     <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="realizzazioni.asp?id_lingua=1&amp;id_pagina=4" />
</rule>
```

but this didn't work
have and idea to do it?

Comment: Use Google to learn all working examples over the internet. Your `url` value in `match` tag is completely wrong.

Comment: I tried a lot of example before write in this forum, evidently I'm missing something, someone that want to help me concretly?